# "Failed to resolve: org.junit:junit:4.12" with AndroidX Test JUnit

Tags: android, junit, android-testing, androidx, android-junit

When I try to add dependency on AndroidX Test JUnit 1.0.0-beta01: `androidTestImplementation androidx.test.ext:junit:1.0.0-beta01`, Gradle Sync fails with the following error:

> Failed to resolve: org.junit:junit:4.12

All manipulations with adding org.junit dependency manually didn't help either.

Comment: Use `testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'`.

Comment: @RakeshKumar This dependency is present, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. We are trying to replace the deprecated AndroidJUnit4 with the ext version, but are seeing this org.junit:junit:4.12 issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above issue has been fixed in **1.0.0-beta02**

'androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.0.0-beta02'

Answer (score 2):

you can exclude 'org.junit' group manually.

```
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.0.0-beta01") {
    exclude group: "org.junit"
}
```